# TextField onEdit listener

Tags: java, javafx-8

I am trying to use TextField in javafx.
The scenario: I have list view populated with specific objects and edit button to edit the object associated with list cell of list view.
When I click on edit button it redirects me to a pane with editing feature where I can edit the name of that object and save it using a save button.
So I have to put validation on save button to make it enable and disable.
If I edit the name in text field then it should enable the save button otherwise it should remains disabled.
I have tried using different methods on text fields as below.

```
textField.textPorperty.addListener(listener -> {
        //Logic to enable disable save button
});
```

As I am using list view, this listener gives me old value as previously edited object which does not satisfy my condition.
I can not use

```
textField.focusedProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldValue, newValue) -> {});
```

as It does not give me expected behavior.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Let us consider a scenario, if the initial text is "issued", which is changed to "issue" and then back to "issued". Will the button remain `enabled`?

Comment: If text is issued changed to issue - button enabled if it again changed to issued without saving the previously changed text it should remain disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement additional logic that decides whether or not a change to the textProperty should change the enablement state of the button. This requires:

- a reference to the initial value (on setting the text to the input, f.i. on changes to selection in the list)
- a boolean property that keeps the enablement state (below it's called buffering)
- a listener to the textField that updates the enablement state as needed

Below is a very simplified example - just to get you started - that extracts those basics into a dedicated class named BufferedTextInput. Buffering is changed internally on:

- set to false if the "subject" value is set or a change is committed/discarded
- set to true once on being notified on the first change of the textField

More complex logic (like not buffering on detecting a change back to the original value) can be implemented as needed.

```
/**
 * Bind disable property of commit/cancel button to actual change. 
 * http://stackoverflow.com/q/29935643/203657
 */
public class ManualBufferingDemo extends Application {

    private Parent getContent() {
        ObservableList<Person> persons = FXCollections.observableList(Person.persons(), 
                person -> new Observable[] {person.lastNameProperty()});
        ListView<Person> listView = new ListView<>(persons);

        TextField lastName = new TextField();
        Consumer<String> committer = text -> System.out.println("committing: " + text);
        BufferedTextInput buffer = new BufferedTextInput(lastName, committer);
        Button save = new Button("Save");
        save.setOnAction(e -> {
            buffer.commit();
        });
        save.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.not(buffer.bufferingProperty()));
        Button cancel = new Button("Cancel");
        cancel.setOnAction(e -> {
           buffer.flush(); 
        });
        listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((source, old, current) -> {
            buffer.setSubject(current.lastNameProperty());
        });
        cancel.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.not(buffer.bufferingProperty()));
        VBox content = new VBox(listView, lastName, save, cancel);
        return content;
    }


    public static class BufferedTextInput {

        private ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper buffering;
        private StringProperty value;
        private TextField input;
        private Consumer<String> committer;

        public BufferedTextInput(TextField input, Consumer<String> committer) {
            buffering = new ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper(this, "buffering", false);
            value = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "");
            this.input = input;
            this.committer = committer;
            input.textProperty().addListener((source, old, current) -> {
                updateState(old, current);
            });
            input.setOnAction(e -> commit());
        }

        private void updateState(String old, String current) {
            if (isBuffering()) return;
            if (value.get().equals(current)) return;
            setBuffering(true);
        }

        public void setSubject(StringProperty value) {
            this.value = value;
            input.setText(value.get());
            setBuffering(false);
        }

        public void commit() {
            committer.accept(input.getText());
            this.value.set(input.getText());
            setBuffering(false);
        }

        public void flush() {
            input.setText(value.get());
            setBuffering(false);
        }

        public boolean isBuffering() {
            return buffering.get();
        }

        public ReadOnlyBooleanProperty bufferingProperty() {
            return buffering.getReadOnlyProperty();
        }

        private void setBuffering(boolean buffer) {
            buffering.set(buffer);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(getContent()));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

For production use, such direct coupling between view and model (f.i. when needing the buffering for a complete form) isn't good enough, further separation might be needed. See [BufferedObjectProperty](https://github.com/kleopatra/swingempire-fx/blob/master/fx8-swingempire/src/java/de/swingempire/fx/property/BufferedObjectProperty.java) and its usage in a FX adaption of the infamous [AlbumManager](https://github.com/kleopatra/swingempire-fx/tree/master/fx8-swingempire/src/demo/de/swingempire/fx/property/albumdemo) example (very crude)